# .NET 3.5 DataGridView Control Display values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Having a problem with the dataGridView control being populated with Display members:

Code:

```
private string settingsFile = @"Data\IntelliSched.xml";
private void loadDataFromXML()
    {
        dataSetXML.ReadXml(settingsFile);
    }
```

DataSet contents:

```
Table -> zone
id
name
----


Table -> postcode
name
code
zone
active
----
```

Pics:

[alt text http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/runtime.PNG](http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/runtime.PNG)

The data is loaded, but it doesn't display the value/displaymember

For info here is the dataset config:
[alt text http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/columns.PNG](http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/columns.PNG)
[alt text http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/dataSetColumns.PNG](http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/dataSetColumns.PNG)
[alt text http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/dataSetTables.PNG](http://www.blazeware.net/examples/datagridview/dataSetTables.PNG)

Am I missing something??

Comment: Show us code used to populate datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer...

The Columns `ColumnMapping` type was set to Element. It needed to be Attribute...

Works now :)